# Facebook video player API xfbml.ready not working on mobile. How to get video instance?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get the facebook video player instance in order to subscribe to different player events. 
In the desktop browser, it just works fine and I'm able to get player instance on the `xfbml.ready` function call but on mobile, it just won't fire.

Here's my code.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

  // Get Embedded Video Player API Instance
  var my_video_player;
  FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
    alert("ready");
    if (msg.type === 'video') {
      my_video_player = msg.instance;
    }
  });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

if anyone want to tryout the code it is here: `http://milracle.github.io/fbPlayer.html`

The same code was working a day ago and now it just stopped working in mobile browsers. Does anyone know about any changes made to the video player itself? I googled it but found nothing. I believe the Stack Overflow community can help as always!

Comment: we have the same stuff and exactly on the same date. 0 changes in our code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by facebook developer team. review thread at: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/338091156930372/?legacy_version=true

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a solution to this issue - I am also pretty sure this has just stopped working recently - I can replicate the issue in chrome dev tools using the mobile device mode.

Comment: Hi Friend, Please use the answer section only for answering to the questions raised. Otherwise, Please use the comment section or raise your own question with the efforts you have put in on the same.

Comment: Thank you @Praveen, it would not let me leave a comment as a new user and I wanted to keep track of this post.

Comment: this has been fixed by fb developer team. check again.